Why does Flutter fail to compile as soon as any package is added to the pubspec.yaml in Android Studio?
I have a basic Flutter project in Android Studio, but whenever I add any external package (example: google_fonts), the compilation fails with a Gradle error.
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider_android:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\dimitri\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\dimitri\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\dimitri\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Here are the details about the installed versions:
Flutter/Dart Versions:
flutter --version
Flutter 3.24.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision dec2ee5c1f (5 days ago) • 2024-11-13 11:13:06 -0800
Engine • revision a18df97ca5
Tools • Dart 3.5.4 • DevTools 2.37.3

Gradle/Java versions:
PS E:\DevEnv\flutter\projects\doit\lesson01\android> ./gradlew -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-08-17 07:06:47 UTC
Revision:     8afbf24b469158b714b36e84c6f4d4976c86fcd5

Kotlin:       1.9.0
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          17.0.12 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.12+8-LTS-286)
OS:           Windows 11 10.0 amd64

Pubspec.Yaml
name: lesson01
description: "DoIt Lesson Project."
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=3.5.0 <4.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  google_fonts: ^6.2.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^5.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

Kindly advice where is the problem source and how can i fix it?

Have you executed flutter pub get after adding the dependency?

Yes sure, and "flutter pub autdated" after it

Can you show us your file pubspec.yaml?

I have added Pubspec.yaml for your review

I can't reproduce the error in my side by simply adding the google_fonts because I didn't encountered the exception after I add that plugin to my pubspec.yaml (i.e., built successful).
So I've decided to represent to you my configurations.
Under the gradle-wrapper.properties:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10.2-bin.zip, or use the latest one, or if necessary, downgrade it. Here is the reference

TIPS:
I also do this way to update the distributionUrl,

PS: C:\to_your_project_directory> cd android


PS: C:\to_your_project_directory\android> .\gradlew clean


PS: C:\to_your_project_directory\android> ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version version_here(x.x.x) --distribution-type all


or


PS: C:\to_your_project_directory\android> ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version version_here(x.x.x)


or


PS: C:\to_your_project_directory\android> ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version latest

Under the settings.gradle:

id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.21" apply false  //if necessary, downgrade it. Here is the reference

Under the android\build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.21' //if necessary, downgrade it.
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

Also, consider this compatibility matrix
Update:
Please use these approaches if necessary:
In your Android Studio, Go to File > Invalidate Caches
Then you can do some troubleshooting practices:

PS: C:\to_your_project_directory> flutter clean
PS: C:\to_your_project_directory> flutter pub get
PS: C:\to_your_project_directory> flutter pub cache repair
PS: C:\to_your_project_directory> cd android
PS: C:\to_your_project_directory\android> .\gradlew clean

Additionals:

PS: C:\to_your_project_directory\android> ./gradlew build --stacktrace --info

To see what plugins or packages introduces the issues
NOTE:
The goal is to make sure that after you configure build.gradle, gradle-wrapper.properties, etc. You also clean the caches, then rebuild them.
I hope it helps!

Thank you for your feedback. I have implemented changes based on your recommendation; however, the error persists. You can review the configurations and error logs at the following link: https://pastebin.com/PcT05h8z.

Please follow the configuration changes for gradle-wrapper.properties as well. To configure: go to File > Project Structure > under the Project tab > Gradle Version > select the compatible version that will work for you. For additional info: https://docs.gradle.org/8.11/userguide/compatibility.html

You have to do some cache clean-up after you done configuring your setup. You need to find out which compatibility issue that is causing it to have build exception. Also try this: File > Invalidate Caches... since you're using Android Studio. Clean your .build as well and then rebuild it again.

Just let us know if there are findings you've observed. Because that is really a tricky one, but most of the time. It's because of the dependencies conflicts or incompatibilities with other development tools.

When I build for Chrome, It works fine. Only for android device it fails. I found out that some packages work fine and some fail. example Google_fonts and flutter_tex causes Gradle to fail during compilation. Something about the versioning i guess, but could not find whats exactly happening

You have to dig deeper into the environment and configurations you have. I know it was tough, but my only advice is that you need to adjust your version of Gradle and Kotlin if you find it necessary. The issue is that the plugin cannot run properly due to an incompatible build and config. The only goal is to use Gradle, Kotlin, or both versions without conflicting with other platforms and plugins.

I am used to the way it should be, so I have a background in it. (XD) Just don't forget to share what you've done to fix it to help others too.

I've updated my answer and added some useful information that you can follow.

I hope that some debugging techniques can help.
